# php artisan serve -- throws error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

So I just beginning learning Laravel today and installed **Composer** and **Laravel**

I created a new application using :-

```
laravel new application
```

in my folder :-

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/
```

However, when I try to run :-

```
php artisan serve
```

I get this error :-

```
Warning: require(/Library/WebServer/Documents/application/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Library/WebServer/Documents/application/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I've already tried updating my composer, didn't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

Running **composer install** gives this :-

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.4.24 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.24].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.24 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[4.0.8].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.7.20 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.20].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.20 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.3].
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup 1.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup[1.0.1].
    - sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup 1.0.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for sebastian/environment 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/environment[2.0.0].
    - sebastian/environment 2.0.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for sebastian/object-enumerator 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/object-enumerator[2.0.1].
    - sebastian/object-enumerator 2.0.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - Installation request for sebastian/resource-operations 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/resource-operations[1.0.0].
    - sebastian/resource-operations 1.0.0 requires php >=5.6.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - Installation request for sebastian/version 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/version[2.0.1].
    - sebastian/version 2.0.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - laravel/framework v5.4.24 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/tinker v1.0.1 requires illuminate/console ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.24].
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v1.0.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.1].
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note:You are using laravel 5.4, which requires php 5.6(minimum), either update your php to 5.6 or use laravel 5.2, that is the reason
>   use this command to install laravel 5.2

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your_project_name "5.2.*"
```

Go to Command Prompt(In Windows)

set path to www/{ur project}

For me : www/laravel5

Then type this command : composer install

It will automatically install all dependency in vendor/

Comment: I'm using Mac and not windows.

Comment: So in mac change the directory to your project routes, i think some dependency are missings

Answer (score 0):

You have to install your project's vendor dependencies with `composer install`:

```
# go to the app root folder
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/
# install vendor dependecies
composer install
```

### Edit

After your question edit, it the error message says clearly that you have an old php version that can not run your new laravel app. You have two options:

**upgrade your php to php 5.6.25 (preferably to php7)**

**downgrade your app( to laravel 5.2.*, the script below will delete it and install a new fresh one**

```
# go to the app root folder
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/
rm -rf application
# install vendor dependecies
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel application 5.2.*
```

Comment: I'm trying to install php7, but everytime after I'm doing installing and i run `php -v`. It still shows the old verison.

Comment: @xanderpower, php7 is installed, you have to correct its path. Look here, https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693#gistcomment-1356378.

Comment: Or if you want to skip this try to uninstall both php versions and install php7 alone.